# Is there a way to mark up or tag mysql transactions for logging?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at switching on logging for mysql as a form of auditing.  I already log all interactions with my database in an external log but, as newer versions are developed, these transactions are likely to change.

I'm aware that I can group my queries together with

```
START TRANSACTION
...
BEGIN
...
COMMIT
```

**Is there a way to "mark up", tag, or add a comment that ends up in the log that can provide meta-information about the transaction?**

e.g.

```
START TRANSACTION //By [user] in [function()], [product], version [XX.YY]
...
BEGIN
...
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL [supports comments](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements006.htm), however, by default MySQL don't write comments to its log, you could either use statement-based binlogs, or enable [`binlog_rows_query_log_events` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_rows_query_log_events), this option is available since 5.7.